# How to Combine data Results from multiple Queries into one Spreadsheet

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, business-intelligence

i have two queries from Sql Sever 2012.

i want to combine the two sets of results in one Excel Spreadsheet.

1. **select * from table1;**

**Results**

[image]

2. select * from table2;

**Results**

[image]

**3. expected Results is spreadsheet with two sheets (tabs)**

[image]

Comment: Excel and SQL are two different beasts.  Can you include sample data directly in your question, formatted as _code_, with four or more spaces on each line?  Then, tell us how these two tables are related to each other.

Comment: If the two SQL select statements return similar column types, you can use UNION to combine the two queries.  If the two SQL select statements do not return similar column types, you probably don't want to be combining them into one spreadsheet anyway.

Comment: @RobertSievers Thank you. I was just trying to be sophisticated.

Comment: Wouldn't importing the data directly into Excel solve your problem?
If it had to be automated, you could record the steps as a macro.